# Login and Session PHP

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication, system

I'm having some problems to check session, to access a page I need to have a session active.

Login process:

```
    //Connect to mysql server
    require "reservation/connect.php";

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['user']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['position'];
            session_write_close();
            //if ($level="admin"){
            header("location: admin/dashboard.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Authentication:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } 
?>
```

Even if i log in from the form, the page doesn't load and redirect me back to index! What i'm doing wrong? I put "require_once('../auth.php');" on the page but it's still not working.

Comment: Never, ever store passwords in plain text in your table, or whatever place you are storing it. Instead use a hash function.

Comment: @B4NZ41 Thanks for the tip, i applied it right now!

Comment: The query looks good, perheaps the problem is with -> if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) - print the value returned with mysql_num_rows($result) - remember TRUE or FALSE are BOOLEAN and not INT.

Comment: @B4NZ41 What i can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because it is getting into `else` part of the statement , which means `$result` is 0 or false.

So the reason is the query must be failing.. So add `mysql_error()` like this..

```
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

To know the exact cause..

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: So basically I have to leave this value to `1` or `true` ?

Comment: @Gumbo, You need to answer that lol. Tsukki..did you add the `mysql_error()` as shown in the code and give a try ?

Comment: @Tsukki `false` is only returned on failure.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yeah, i did it and still not working. There's nothing wrong with the auth page?