# Login implementation in PHP

Tags: php, session, post

Suppose, I have two pages login.php and index.php. In index.php I have two buttons Login and register.After clicking the buttons ,the user is directed to login.php.

If I want to implement a login functionality using PHP, something related to facebook such that the if a user has logged in before, then it bypasses the index page once the username and password are set and directly lands into the login page. Is $_SESSION a proper way of doing it.

For example:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Ayu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) { ?>
        <h1>Hi <?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?></h1>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
        <h1>Login</h1>
<?php echo (isset($_GET["error"])) ? '<p>You idiot!</p>' : ""; ?>
        <form action="new-user.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>
                    <strong>Username</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="username" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <strong>Password</strong>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
<?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the login functionality, I am setting the $_SESSION values

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (count($_POST))
        if ($_POST["username"] == "ayu" && $_POST["password"] == "shee") {
            $_SESSION["user"] = "Ayushi";
            header("Location: ./");
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION["user"]);
            header("Location: ./?error");
        }
?>
```

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10097986/916000

Comment: i did that only. but somehow, after I refresh the page, I come back to index.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login and Session PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581073/login-and-session-php)

Comment: Can you post where you redirect the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes using and creating (`$_SESSION`) session is the correct way to check logged in  users.

> `$_SESSION` is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This
>   simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script.
>   There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions
>   or methods.

Check for session on very top of a page, if found redirect to index else to login page.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
```

Refer this simple login example using my sql in php [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm)

**EDIT**

As requested by OP - if you want to hide a particular section in index.php page based on session value or say if a user is logged in or not that can be done like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
?>
<form>
   <input type="submit" name="whatever" />
   <!-- Other Fields -->
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Html Form in the above code will only be shown if a user is logged in else it will be hidden.

Comment: And if I have only one index.php and two different sections that I want to toggle with.then how should I do that ? Because I cannot use header location there.

Comment: In that case you can hide or show html section or blocks based on session value. let me edit my answer to add this

Comment: Just one more confusion that I have, when I set $_SESSION, will that be set until I end the session, irrespective of the number of times I refresh or run the code?

Comment: Default timeout depends on the server configuration or the relevant directives (session.gc_maxlifetime) in php.ini . Typically the default is 24 minutes (1440 seconds), but your webhost may have altered the default to something else. so you can end the session based on the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Session is best way to implement the same. You can use the below php code to solve your problem

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST))
        if ($_POST["username"] == "ayu" && $_POST["password"] == "shee") {
            $_SESSION["user"] = "Ayushi";
            header("Location: ./");
        } else {
if($_SESSION["user"]!=''){
            unset($_SESSION["user"]);
}
            header("Location: ./?error");
        }else{
/* Write code for form */
}
?>
```